# Java getting UTC+2 when it would be UTC+1

Tags: java, date, timezone

Last sunday we change the time (-1h) in middle europe. I was making some tests but something does not let me sleep with the java time parser. This is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateFormatPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    String dateUtc = "2016-10-09 12:50:00";

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUtc = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern);
    dateFormatUtc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLisboa = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern);
    dateFormatLisboa.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Lisboa"));

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatMadrid = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern);
    dateFormatMadrid.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatParis = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern);
    dateFormatParis.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));

    System.out.println("UTC: "+dateUtc);
    try {
        Date d = dateFormatUtc.parse(dateUtc);
        System.out.println("Lisboa: "+dateFormatLisboa.format(d));
        System.out.println("Madrid: "+dateFormatMadrid.format(d));
        System.out.println("Paris: "+dateFormatParis.format(d));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the output

```
UTC: 2016-10-09 12:50:00
Lisboa: 2016-10-09 12:50:00
Madrid: 2016-10-09 14:50:00
Paris: 2016-10-09 14:50:00
```

Why the difference between UTC and Madrid time are 2 hours? Now in madrid is UTC+1.

Thanks.

Comment: What date did the clocks change? What happens if you do `String dateUtc = "2016-11-02 12:50:00";`?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was blind with the time change and I had not realized with the string date was earlier :(

Comment: No worries, its the classic, needing another pair of eyes, thing. I have solved so much just by calling someone else to look at things.

Comment: FYI, those date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Migrating to java.time will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The times are correct as the clocks changed on the 30th October at 2am

if you change you code to this

```
String dateUtc = "2016-11-09 12:50:00";
```

You get this output, giving the correct 1 hour difference.

```
UTC: 2016-11-09 12:50:00
Lisboa: 2016-11-09 12:50:00
Madrid: 2016-11-09 13:50:00
Paris: 2016-11-09 13:50:00
```

The timezone is due to the when the date object is actually referencing. So it is correct for that time

Answer (score 3):

The accepted Answer by French is correct. The values overlapped the cutover in Daylight Saving Time (DST).

I am just pointing out that your code is using old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Parse the input value as a `LocalDateTime` because it lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with ISO 8601 format used by default in the java.time classes for parsing/generating strings.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-10-09 12:50:00".replace( " " , "T" ) );
```

We know from the business context that UTC is intended for this input string. So assign an offset of UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Adjust into a time zone by applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Lisboa" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
```

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the application must run in java 7. As you explain, java 8 has fresh libs to work with dates, fair and necessary, aleluya!

Comment: @JonAnder Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in ThreeTen-Backport project.